# How can I set a delay before deleting an embed with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Currently this bot will post the embed when I call the command and then instantly delete the command  message like I want. I want it to delete the embed as well, but I want to add a delay before it deletes the embed. What am I doing wrong here?

```
command(client, 'title' , (message) => {

   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

      .setTitle('Title Here')

   message.channel.send(embed).then

      setTimeout(() => {

       (message => message.delete(embed))

      }, 5000)
  
 

   

   if(message.content.startsWith('!' + 'title')) {
      message.delete()}

 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you really messed up the .then

.then is another way of handling promises and callbacks.. but in your code, there is no callback.

what you should do is put the code that deletes the message outside and above the .then

afterwards, make sure that .then actually has a callback. it should look like this:

```
command(client, 'title' , (message) => {

   if(message.content.startsWith('!' + 'title')) {
      message.delete()
   }

   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Title Here')

   message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {

      setTimeout(() => {
        msg.delete()
      }, 5000)
 })
```

what this does is that, when you run the command, it deletes the invocation. it then sends the embed and waits until the discord api responds saying “the message was sent successfully!”, to which it runs the timeout for 5 seconds and deletes the embed.

Comment: Or you can just say `msg.delete({ timeout: 1000 * 5 /* 5 seconds in ms */ })`